# How to install package in 86 hosts in the same time (RHEL)?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, package-management, python3

I would like to install python3 and python3.4 in my office servers. There are 86 hosts and I am confused how I do that in the same time.
In this time, I found my solution like this

```
pssh -h host_86.txt -i "yum install -y epel-release && yum install -y python34"
```

Is python3 included in python3.4 package automatically or separately?
Is my solution right to do that?
The OS is RHEL 7 and I found the yum package from here: [How to install Python 3.4 on CentOS 6 & 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23317640/8162936). Do I need to install python34-setuptools and easy_install-3.4?

I am junior system administrator and confused about how to handle 86 hosts a day.

Comment: Why have you not put a deployment and management solution in place yet, with so many servers?

Comment: Satellite and Puppet would make this very easy as you could just create a puppet module to install the python packages. That's what we have where I work.

Comment: Thank you for your response guys. Exactly, i don't manage the servers from data center. I just received the Master server auth such as username and password for each servers. i don't know what they did to their rack servers. And i don't understand what is "deployment and management solution" ?

Comment: Take a look at [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)) or [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)). I can only recommend both products if you have thought of a concept in advance.

Comment: Could you give me small explanation according to Puppet ?
What does Puppet do ? Should i install Puppet into 86 hosts or only 1 host but require ssh no-key to other 85 hosts ?

Comment: A management solution is a long term goal, and you should ask your boss about any plans in that direction.  If you get a blank stare, start doing research and explain to him issues like what you are facing now and how much easier it is to deal with using a proper mgmnt system.  For right now, I'd fire up VirtualBox (or similar) and setup a machine as close as you can get to what you are dealing with in production and do some testing on just a single install.  Then decide if you can script it, and check if the machine is in the correct pre-condition.  Then use your ssh command.

Comment: Thank you buddy.. thank you very much... i am a internship junior sysadmin... this is my first time to deal with this scheme... omg... I will note Puppet and Ansible... in the mean time, i will make 2 hosts as a experiement server using pssh... thx so much guys